# Asp.net Identity 2.x without Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a webpage that doesnt want/need third party logins and i dont want to pollute the database with unused tables (afaik claims are stored in its own table), Is it possible to use Identity 2.x with only User and Roles functionality? 
I can only find implementations (through google search) with only the User part, like this [one](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity).

I could certainly use that and create a Role table, but if i do that then could not use this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "UserType1")]
```

Edit: i think claims are only needed for third party login, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes.  It's not too bad, you just need to implement your own UserStore

Answer (score 0):

Claims are not needed for third-party logins. Claims are just bits of information stored in auth-cookie when user is logged in.

No, you can't have Identity framework without claims, as it sets the principal to be `ClaimsPrincipal`. But if you don't need/want claims, you just don't have to use it anywhere. And authentication through roles will still work.
If you don't want to have `UserClaims` table in database, you'll have to implement your own user store that does not have claims table. However, I think this is too much effort just not to have an empty table in a db.